# use a function to store each ajax call data

Tags: javascript, ajax, scope

I want to store data between ajax calls, so that I can have my accumulated data in an object.
I can get the data of each of the calls, but I am not able to accumulate the data in one whole array.

I created the `dataAccumulator ()` function, so that when I call `accumData.append` the data for a single call can be pushed to the holder array.

I keep getting the error `Cannot read property 'append' of undefined` or `Uncaught TypeError: dataAccumulator is not a function` no matter where I declare or call the function...

This is the code:

```
var inter;
var dataAccumulator = dataAccumulator(); //object of interest

function startTempMonit()
{
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        time= 0;
        inter = setInterval(function()
        {
            $.ajax // ajax call starts
            ({ 
                //not relevant for the question. arguments removed...
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                //problem here. data is foreach call.
                //I would like to accumulate each of the data to handle the whole here.
                dataAccumulator.append(data);  
            });
            time= time + 0.5;
        }, 500)
    });
};

function dataAccumulator () {
    let accumData = [];
    console.log("accumData function created")

    function append(data) {
        accumData.push(data);
    
        console.log(accumData); //log the accumulated data each time
    }

    this.append = append;
};
```

I guess my problem is with js scopes. I want to keep my `accumData` array available inside the ajax call `.done`. That is the summary of my problem.

Comment: You have problems with names. You have two entities named `dataAccumulator`, variable and function. And then you call `accumData()` as function, but there is not such function

Comment: thanks, that was a typo because I changed the name to the function when the code was pasted fo the question post. Corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is always to get rid of global variables. The second step is to use events instead of global state.

Register a callback that is called every time data has arrived. Then work with the data in the callback.

```
function startTempMonit(callback) {
    var time = 0;
    return setInterval(function () {
        $.ajax({ 
            url: '....',
            data: '.....' + tiempo
            dataType: '.....',
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            console.log("received", data);
            callback(data);
        });
        time += 0.5;
    }, 500);
}

$(function () {
    var inter, accumData = [];
    
    $("#buttonStart").click(function () {
        inter = startTempMonit(function (data) {
            accumData.push(data);
            // do something, i.e. add it to a table or a chart
        });
    });
    $("#buttonStop").click(function () {
        clearInterval(inter);
    });
});
```